# How to pass my data one activity to another activity

Tags: android-intent, android-json

```
[{
    "name":"pawan",
    "image":"HTTP://example.com/Pavan/errorlog.png",
    "age ":"24",
    "address":"Pawan",
    "town":"PAWAN"
}]
```

I am passing all values, in first Activity I am displaying 3 fields, in second activity I want to display all fields using Intents.

Comment: provide some specific details of your problem.

Answer (score 0):

While your data have a `JSONArray` format, you can pass it as a `String`:

In your first activity:

```
intent.putString("personsList", yourJsonArray.toString);
```

And then, to retrieve it in your second activity:

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(getIntent().getStringExtra("personsList"));
```